# Не получается скачать golang 1.8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, golang

Привет. Не могу поставить golang 1.8.

Захожу на [официальный сайт](https://golang.org/dl/). Собственно, жму на ссылку [go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz (87MB)](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz), по которой происходит скачивание собранной версии. Распаковываю архив, захожу в `bin` и к своему удивлению, получаю:

```
$ ~/Downloads/go/bin$ go version
go version go1.7.4 linux/amd64
```

В чём может быть косяк?

Comment: `./go version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда выполняешь `go` в командной строке, то на самом деле запускается go, который у тебя уже установлен в системе. Чтобы проверить, где находится исполняемый файл, можно выполнить команду:

```
which go
```

Чтобы выполнить `go` из текущей директории, нужно сделать:

```
./go
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался (=